# Retrieving data from Firebase using Admin SDK for .NET

Tags: .net, firebase, firebase-admin

I can't seem to find any information about retrieving data from Firebase Realtime Database using Firebase Admin SDK for .NET

Is it simply not implemented yet? I can find the information for Node and Python, but it seems like the .NET SDK is still missing this functionality. Has anyone else encountered this roadblock?

API reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/dotnet

Comment: Retrieving data from what? Firestore/RTDB/Storage? Some of these services have .NET clients maintained by Google Cloud.

Comment: My bad, I've edited the question. I'm trying to retrieve data from Firebase realtime database using the Admin SDK. I've done it using NodeJS, but it doesn't seem to be doable from .NET

Comment: RTDB doesn't have an official server-side .NET API from Firebase. You will have to either use the REST API or look for 3rd party options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just received this response from Firebase Support. It seems the Admin SDK for .NET is still being developed:

> It indeed is not yet added, and although we cannot provide any more details on the current projects of the engineering team it is already an item to be worked on.
> Please take note that we cannot provide any details or timelines as of when it will be worked and released but it will surely be checked onto. You may keep an eye on our release notes and our blog for any further updates

Release notes: https://firebase.google.com/support/releases

Blog: https://firebase.googleblog.com/